# HTTP call to another server at route not found rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, http-status-code-404

i have strange kind of requirement i want to completely change the behavior of **No route matches**  in rails, instead of raising exception or custom page i want to make a HTTP call to another server when i get 404/no route matches in rails. Currently i am doing it wrong way

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found


  def record_not_found
      #HTTP call

  end
```

but its not working. Do i need to change RoutingError default class of rails ?
thanks

Comment: did you redirect_to "http_url"  inside the controller action?

Comment: @RajAdroit i am not redirecting inside `record_not_found` instead i am making HTTP call and will return response of HTTP call back instead of 404 error

Comment: i am not able to understand you, can you post sample http request and response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**No route matches [GET] "** is not an Exception. It's just an error, which makes debugging easy in development environment. If you want to handle it  then use below mentioned code in your routes.rb file.

**Make sure you define this configuration at the end of all other routes definitions.**  If no route matches, then this will search for **'record_not_found'** action defined in **application_controller**

```
 #routes.rb
get '*path',
    controller: 'application', 
    action: 'record_not_found'

 #application_controller.rb     
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def record_not_found
      #add your call to another server 
      render nothing: true   
    end

end
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It _is_ an Exception.  Your screenshot is the result of `ActionController::RoutingError` being raised.  `ActionController::RoutingError` inherits from `ActionController::ActionControllerError` which inherits from `StandardError` which inherits from `Exception`.

Comment: @Ajay Yes its almost the same i figured out Thanks